# Update SPLIST Help Problem?

Tags: development, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise

SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;

```
            SPList oList = web.Lists["MyList"];
            SPListItem oListItem = oList.Items[1];

            oListItem["Name"] = TextBox_Name.Text;
            oListItem.Update();
```

//my list wont get updated why?

Comment: what's the problem you are facing? any error? or just it does not get updated, can you please debug your code and provide debug information/error log

Comment: Maybe he don't change the name of list or nameof field. I think that is main problem here.

Comment: The code you provided should work fine unless u have incorrect `list name` or `internal name` of the field in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I presume this is in a webpart if so try the following to see if it works :)

```
        SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;

        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

        SPList list = Web.Lists["MyList"];

        SPListItem oListItem = List.Items[1];

        oListItem["Name"] = TextBox_Name.Text;
        oListItem.Update();

        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
```

more info on AllowUnsafeUpdates:

http://hristopavlov.wordpress.com/2008/05/16/what-you-need-to-know-about-allowunsafeupdates/

full example

http://www.mssharepointtips.com/tip.asp?id=1176

also like others have noted that you need to check your list name is called "MyList" and its "Name" that you want to update ;)

hope it helps :)